# Questions concerning Z-Normalization in Dynamic Time Warping

Tags: classification, normalization, dynamic-time-warping

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/dtw-dynamic-time-warping-requires-prior-normalization/16035) I found [this](http://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emueen/DTW.pdf) very nice presentation. On page 46 one can read the following:

> Essentially all datasets must have every subsequence z-normalized.
> There are a handful of occasions where it does not make sense to
> z-normalize, but in those cases, DTW probably does not make sense
> either.

I tried to use Z-Normalization with the following code in Python:

```
trainX = stats.zscore(trainX)
testX = stats.zscore(testX)
```

I.e. I normalized the entire data-set. This resulted in a slighlty worse performance of my classifier. On page 48 of the presentation mentioned above I read the following:

> Preempting a common misunderstanding: It is not sufficient to normalize
> the entire time series. You must normalize each subsequence.

Concerning this I have the following questions:

1. Does the above statement mean that I should normalize the entire time series **and** each subsequence or just each subsequence?
2. What's the reasoning for either choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should JUST normalize each sequence.

BTW, 128 test datasets here https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data_2018/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'll give it a try.